# Is my circuit solution correct?

Tags: inductor, passive-networks, homework

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH8CY1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have to calculate the energy of the inductors magnetic field at **t = 6 ms**.

I am given: *E = 50 V, R1 = 10 Ω, R2 = 15 Ω, R3 = 20 Ω and L = 0.1 H*

---

So at **t < 0**, the switch is closed and the current is flowing. In the parallel section, we get I1 and I2, since the inductor formula is time-dependent and it is t < 0 the inductor will have no voltage and will behave like a wire.

I calculate the total resistance in the parallel and add R3 for Rtotal;

$$ R_{total} = (\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2})^{-1} + R_3 = 26 Ω $$

$$ I = \frac{U}{R_{total}} = \frac{50}{26} = 1.92 A $$

Now I can calculate the voltages in the circuit parts;

$$ U_{R3} = I * R_3 = 1.92 * 20 = 38.40 V $$

The voltage in parallel should be the same so UR1 = UR2 and together with UR3 should amount to 50 V, 50 - 38.40 = 11.60V in parallel.

At **t = 0** the switch is open. The current stops flowing from the source and the depletion of the inductor starts.

It is a falling function the only voltage provider is the inductor;

$$ I = \frac{U_L}{R_1 + R_2} \rightarrow 1.92 = \frac{U_L}{25} \rightarrow U_L = 48 V $$

So since it is t = 0 things will remain the same;

$$ I_L = 1.92 \exp{\frac{-0}{\tau}} = 1.92 A $$

$$ U_L = 48 \exp{\frac{-0}{\tau}} = 48 V $$

At **t = 6ms = 0.006 s**;

$$ \tau = \frac{L}{R_{total}} = \frac{0.1}{25} = 0.004 $$

$$ I_L = 1.92\exp{\frac{-0.006}{0.004}} = 0.42 A $$

$$ U_L = 48\exp{\frac{-0.006}{0.004}} = 10.71 V $$

The energy of the inductor at t = 6 ms;

$$ W_L = \frac{Li^2}{2} = \frac{0.1 * 0.42^2}{2} = 0.008 J $$

Comment: I think it's useful to think of an inductor as a form of current source instead of voltage, because "it tries" to keep the current steady. And if you think about the current which is going to flow, which of the three resistors is/are in the current path when the switch opens?

Comment: So the current goes thru R1 and R2 only it won go thru R3=20Ω

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: so I=UL/Rtotal -> 1.92=UL/25 -> UL=48V     Tau=L/Rtotal=0.1/25=0.004 ,

iL=1.92*e^(-0.006/0.004)=0.42A ,

uL=48*e^(-0.006/0.004)=10.71V ,

energy of the inductor at t=6ms WL=(L*i^2)/2=0.008J

Comment: Your diagram should indicate which is R1, R2 etc.. Don't expect folk to keep glancing up and down because it drives me mad doing that and you don't want to get me mad.

Comment: "tau=L/Rtotal=0.1/26=0.003" Where did you get a  of 3 ms? After the switch opens, the inductor "defluxes" over 10 and 15 ohms in series. Which gives =100mH/25 Ω = 4ms. Also, 0.1/26 does not equal 0.003.

Comment: Still not quite there I fear. The inductor will only keep the current active which is running though itself not the one through the whole circuit.

Comment: Yeah I get it only thru the parallel part which is then actually a series the other resistor plays no role in tau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At t < 0:**

The switch is closed and the current is flowing. We assume that the system has reach the stationary phase. So, the inductor (its formula is time-dependent) the inductor will have no voltage and will behave like a wire.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xv1B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You calculated the total resistance for this circuit:

$$ R_{total} = (\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2})^{-1} + R_3 ≃ 26 Ω $$
Which leads to:
$$ I_T = \frac{U}{R_{total}} = \frac{50}{26} ≃ 1.92 A $$
Now, you can calculate the voltages **and currents** through the circuit:
$$ U_{R3}  = I_T*R_{3} = 1.92 *20 ≃ 38.40V $$
The voltage in parallel should be the same so UR1 = UR2. Together with UR3 should amount to 50 V, UR1 = UR2 = 50 - 38.40 = 11.60V in parallel.

With ohm law, you can determine the currents going through the resistor and deduce the current going through the inductor:

$$ U_{R1} = R_{1} * i_{1} => I_{1} ≃ 1.15A $$
$$ U_{R2} = R_{2} * i_{2} => I_{2} ≃ 0.77A $$

Resistor R2 and inductor L are components in serie:

But $$ I_{R_2} = I_L ≃ 0.77A $$

**At t = 0 :**

The switch is open. The current stops flowing from the source and the depletion of the inductor starts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzLrdB.png)</sup>

You will notice that I change the convention of the voltage for the resistor R1 in order to keep the voltage arrow of R1 in the "oposite direction" of the current arrow going through R1.

It is a falling function the only voltage provider is the inductor. It comes from the differential equation of the circuit:

Use the Kirchhoff law for meshes:
$$ U_{L} + U_{R1} + U_{R2} = 0 $$
But, you know that, for an inductor, $$ U_{L} = L\frac{di(t)}{dt} $$ with **i(t) the current going through the inductor !**

The ohm law gives you: $$ U_{R1} = R_{1} * i(t) $$ and $$ U_{R2} = R_{2} * i(t) $$
This leads to:
$$ L\frac{di(t)}{dt} + R_{1} * i(t) + R_{2} * i(t) = 0 $$
The solution of this differential equation is:
$$ i(t) = cst*e^{ \frac{-t}{tau} } $$ with `cst` to be determined and `tau` the characteristic time of your circuit for t>0 with $$ tau = \frac{L}{R_{1}+R_{2}} = 0.004s  $$ (this is math)

Now, (***this is your mistake***), you have to find `cst`, for that you know that the current flowing an inductor is continuous, so:

$$ i(t = 0^{-}) = i(t = 0^{+}) $$
Or $$ i(t = 0^{-}) = I_L ≃ 0.77A ≠ 1.92 A !$$

Consequently, you have:
$$ i(t) = 0.77*e^{ \frac{-t}{0.004} } $$

Which leads you to t=6ms:
$$ i(t) = 0.77*e^{ \frac{-0.006}{0.004} } ≃ 0.17A $$

So: The energy of the inductor at t = 6 ms is: 
$$ W(t=6ms) = \frac{L*(i(t=6ms))^2}{2} = \frac{0.1*0.17^2}{2} ≃ 0.0015J $$